# DeamonsSet "Stuck" in Google Container Engine 1.2.0

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I did an upgrade of GKE to v1.2 yesterday and started to try out the DaemonSet feature (beta), didn't work as expected and i wanted to delete it from the cluster. What happened is that the delete operation failed and now the DaemonSet is in a inconsistent state and restarts all my other pods every 5 min.

What can be done without deleting and recreating the whole cluster? I did try to apply the DaemonSet with a busybox like that :

And the DS looks like that :

[image]

[image]

The deleting operations fails :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the state of the DaemonSet is inconsistent, you can try to delete it using `--cascade=false?` flag.